# Privilege Escalation Mitigation

Tags: http, json, privilege-escalation

What is the best protection against Privilege Escalation vulnerability in web application. Basically I am able to change the HTTP response in JSON format from USER ID to ADMIN ID to get access to the admin account system.

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Do you really mean changing the user ID in the response and not the request?

Comment: Yes in the response not the request.

Comment: So, the admin functions are sent to the client, and unlocked client-side with the content of the JSON?

Comment: yes basically I am able to capture the response through proxy and modify the response.

Comment: So you are doing client-side authorization checks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In kind of security you talk generally of 3 points:

1. identification
2. authentification
3. authorization

You are missing point 2/"never trust the client": You identify the client by the ID and give him the rights based on the ID sent from the client. Like you saw this fails because the client can lie. The most common solutions for authentification at websites are:

- Sending an authentification token like a password with the request AND CHECKING SERVERSIDE
- Using sessions (like cookies) AND CHECKING SERVERSIDE